# How do I select from Postgres in a Docker Container from Powershell correctly?

Tags: postgresql, docker, powershell

The task is to be able to select / insert / alter from Powershell to a Postgres database in a docker container on a server (Ubuntu).

What works so far: Connect to the database in the container from the server, using:

```
sudo docker exec dockercontainer psql -U "database" -c "SELECT * FROM vertrag;"
```

Trying to move it to my computer in a ps1 script, I am using:

```
echo <password> | 
  plink -no-antispoof user@server.de sudo docker exec dockercontainer psql -U "database" - c "SELECT * FROM vertrag;"
```

This suddenly doesn't yield any results. Somehow it throws up this result:

```
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "docker-compose.yml" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "bla" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "service-log.log" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "server.log" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "sicherung" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "snap" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "test.sh" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "umgebung_zuruecksetzen.sh" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "FROM" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "vertrag" ignored
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  database "container" does not exist
```

This seems to be the contents of the folder /home/user in the Ubuntu system.

I am at my wits end. I already used this additions for ps1 to call some scripts in another docker container and this works perfectly fine:

```
echo <password> |
  plink -no-antispoof user@server.de sudo docker exec dockercontainer sh /batch/batch.sh argument1 argument2 --argument3=xy --argument4=1234
```

If someone has an idea, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: How would you do this if the database was running on the remote system, but not in a container?  If you use a `docker run -p` option to start the container, then you should be able to connect to it in the exact same way, without a `docker exec` layer.  If your underlying transport is ssh, you might be able to use a port-forward option there too (like `ssh -L`) and run `psql` locally, without any of the parts that come before it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to place quotes around the psql command:

```
echo <password> | plink -no-antispoof user@server.de sudo docker exec dockercontainer 'psql -U "database" - c "SELECT * FROM vertrag;"'
```

Comment: Your original command uses `-c` v. ``- c`` in this answer.